# Convert Date format to insert into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-format

I'm receiving the date in '**Sun Jun 20 00:40:27 IST 2021**' format. Which I need to insert to my MySQL database in `datetime(6)` format.

I used

```
STR_TO_DATE('Sun Jun 20 00:40:27 IST 2021','%d/%m/%Y %T')
```

and received

> Incorrect datetime value: 'Sun Jun 20 00:40:27 IST 2021' for function
> str_to_date error.

I also tried

```
date_format('Sun Jun 20 00:40:27 IST 2021','%d/%m/%Y %T')
```

and received

> Incorrect datetime value: 'Sun Jun 20 00:40:27 IST 2021

Can anyone guide me to fix it?

PS: I'm using `prepared statement`, `executeBatch()` to insert data to table.

Comment: Do you really think that `'Sun Jun 20 00:40:27 IST 2021'` matches the pattern of `'%d/%m/%Y %T'`?

Comment: no, I want to convert to `'%d/%m/%Y %T'` format.

Comment: No, you certainly don't want that; you want it to be a datetime value, which has no format. You need to tell `STR_TO_DATE` how to parse your string, so your format must match what is in the string you pass to it.

Comment: You're confusing `STR_TO_DATE` with `DATE_FORMAT`. The first parses a date string, the second formats a date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To store into a `DATETIME`, use `STR_TO_DATE()` where you describe the format of the string:

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Sun Jun 20 00:40:27 IST 2021', "%a %b %d %H:%i:%s IST %Y");
```

--> `2021-06-20 00:40:27`

As a separate step, you can `SELECT` the Datetime in a different format using `DATE_FORMAT()` with a *different* formatting string.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2021-06-20 00:40:27', '%d/%m/%Y');
```

--> `20/06/2021 00:40:27`

You cannot do both conversions in a single function call.

Storing into `DATETIME(6)` will store `2021-06-20 00:40:27.000000`.  (In your example, the `(6)` is wasted.

If you are using `LOAD DATA`, there is a way to do the `STR_TO_DATE` as you do the insert.

I don't know how to generalize on "IST"; notice that I essentially stepped over it in my sample code.

Comment: `IST` is a named timezone. Unfortunately, `STR_TO_DATE` doesn't have timezone support (it's `%Z` in `strptime()`).

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks.  That's what I was fishing for.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Date-Format]

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2021-06-20 00:40:27', '%d/%m/%Y');
```